# UItextView dismiss keyboard on tap outside the textview

Tags: ios, uiview, uitextview, uikeyboard

i have a `custom UIView` which is presented from a `UIViewController`. This view controller can present one of several such views. One of these views has a `UITextView`. when one begins entering text in the `UITextView`, the keyboard is shown. however, I want to dismiss the keyboard whenever the user taps anywhere outside the textview. as multiple `UIViews` can be presented by the UIViewController based on certain condition, I encapsulated the `UITextView` delegate methods etc in the `custom UIView`, I did this using Notifications from within the `custom UIView` like

```
- (void)configureView
{ 
NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

[nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:
 UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

[nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:
 UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

self.tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                           action:@selector(didTapAnywhere:)];
}

-(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *) note {
[self addGestureRecognizer:self.tapRecognizer];
}

-(void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *) note
{
[self removeGestureRecognizer:self.tapRecognizer];
}

-(void)didTapAnywhere: (UITapGestureRecognizer*) recognizer {    
[self.detailsTextView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

however, when the didTapAnywhere is called, the keyboard does not get dismissed even when the resignfirstresponder ties place. FYI, the delegate for the `UITextView` is the `custom UIView`.

ple help in how to do this

Comment: Throw an NSLog() in there to see if your method is even being called.

Comment: yes didTapAnywhere is being called when i tap anywhere outside the UITextView

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

> [self.view endEditing:YES];

instead of resigning the first responder. This should do the trick.
What's weird is why isn't the standard approach working...

Answer (score 1):

You have to include `UITextViewDelegate` to your class and `detailsTextView.delegate = self` in your `viewDidLoad` or any ware you initialise your detailsTextView..  I hope this will solve your problem...